# perfomance testing saga microservices

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, microservices, saga

I want to know what will be the best practice for testing a microservice(orchestrator) which is a part of Saga. I have multiple microservices of which one is an orchestrator like what happens in a Saga. The Orchestrator receives request over a REST channel and returns 202 and immediately start the Saga. I want to conduct a performance test once the orchestrator start the Saga and ends it. The request is stored in Database and there is a status column which keeps changing as it completes its various stages like New, processing, Done. Done or Failed is the final status.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler to kick off the job.

Then you can add a [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) to query the database with the [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler until the related job is "done".

The whole sequence can be put under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), this way you will get total execution time in one "synthetic" sample result.

Example test plan:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri. I will give it a shot. However can i use any field value from the json payload to query the dB? For e.g if the json payload has "customerId": "12345" and so on, can I use as $customerId to query the table which stored the customer id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrk` or `ab` to fire request to the REST orchestrator, and then watch the output.

I have done a similar performance test for Saga in go: https://en.dtm.pub/other/performance.html

Comment: hi @yedf, thanks for your suggestion, will take a look.